# Laravel Swagger (l5-swagger) multiple apiKey in header securityScheme

Tags: laravel, swagger-ui, openapi, darkaonlinel5-swagger, l5-swagger

My api requires two fields in the header and it's described in the `config/l5-swagger.php` like this:

```
        'securityDefinitions' => [
            'securitySchemes' => [
                'app_id' => [
                    'type' => 'apiKey',
                    'description' => 'API integration application identifier',
                    'name' => 'X-App-Id',
                    'in' => 'header',
                ],
                'access_token' => [
                    'type' => 'apiKey',
                    'description' => 'API integration access token',
                    'name' => 'X-Access-Token',
                    'in' => 'header',
                ],
            ],
            'security' => [
                [
                    'app_id' => [],
                    'access_token' => [],
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

On the generated api documentation, when I click `Authorize` it renders the form with separate fields like this:

[image]

How do I tell `l5-swagger` to merge both of these fields together and not be treated separately?

Comment: I have no idea about swagger, but I checked out the documentation and they are using a YML or YAML (if I am not misreading), it says you have to define the first one with a dash and the next one WITHOUT a dash, that will tell it is an AND and not an OR bewteen the headers, but I have no idea about PHP. Is that PHP array the only config you have? This is the doc I am talking about: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/#multiple

Comment: I've seen that it's possible with swagger, `l5-swagger` is a package for auto generating the swagger definition in json/yaml based on annotations, i am just not sure how to tell it to merge these

Comment: I am not sure how to help you, because the official documentation is only talking about YAML, so I have no idea about how is a JSON interpreted for that same case

Comment: Just to try it out, what happens if you do: `'security' => [ [ 'app_id', 'access_token' ] ]`?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct. This is just how Swagger UI renders API key pairs. Here's an existing enhancement request to improve the representation of API key pairs:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3521

Comment: ah I see, thanks I wasn't aware